# RNDIS driver not automatically loaded in Ubuntu-20.04

Tags: ubuntu, rndis

I am pretty new to Linux/Ubuntu configuration.

- my device was loaded with Ubuntu-20.04 by unknown colleague.
- my device has mPCIe socket for MDG200 (4G modem)
- I was expecting to see a virtual Ethernet port after inserting MDG200.
- But, it seems that RNDIS is not loaded automatically after inserting MDG200
- (Thus I couldn't see the virtual Ethernet port)
- (please see screenshots of "lsmod" results, **before/after** inserting MDG200)

Anybody knows how to install RNDIS driver in Ubuntu?
Thanks!

[image: before inserting MDG200]

[image: after inserting MDG200]

Comment: Did you manage to get this working or any update on this?